# What is the difference between docker ps -all and docker ps --all

Tags: docker

The docker commands [reference for ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) mentions that

```
docker ps -a
docker ps --all
```

commands show the list of all containers.

While working on dockers, I mistakenly was using the command

```
docker ps -all
```

and it gave me the list of last container I ran, even though **its status was Exited only**.

[image]

Wasted much time due to this confusion. Have been looking for its official reference and couldn't find any. I was wondering if its a bug or am I missing something.

Comment: `-all` identical to `-a -l`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By convention on linux, `-xyz` is shorthand for `-x -y -z`, so it looks like docker's taking `-all` to be `-a -l -l`, or just `-a -l`.

From the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#options) quoted below, you can see that `-a` is shorthand for `-all`, and `-l` is shorthand for `--latest`, so you get shown the latest container run.

> --all , -a        Show all containers (default shows just running)
>
> ...
>
> --latest , -l      Show the latest created container (includes all states)

From the descriptions in the reference, it looks like `-l` effectively overrides `-a`, so your output for `docker ps -all` should be the same as for `docker ps -l`.

Comment: Just checked. `docker ps -all` is giving same output as `docker ps -l`